# Phonegap Serve, Build Phonegap e MySql

Tags: mysql, apache-cordova

Estou desenvolvendo um app usando `jquery mobile` e `phonegap`. 
Pergunta: por que quando testo a aplicação no `'phonegap serve'` do `node.js` funciona e quando faço download do `apk` criado pelo `Buil Phonegap` não?

Exemplo: se tento me comunicar com um banco de dados (`mysql`) externo através do phonegap serve funciona normal, mas pelo apk não.

Meu código de consulta é:

```
$(document).on('click', '#envcep', function() {
 var cep1 = $("#cep").val();
 var n = cep1.length;
 if (n < 8) {
  $("#mesg").text("CEP incompleto.");
  $("#dialog2").popup('open');
  return true;
 } else {

   var data = $("#app").serialize();
   $.ajax
      ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://meuwebsite.com.br/aplicativo/cep.php",
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       success:

    function(resposta) {...
```

Detalhe: o meu config.xml já está com:
access origin="*" 
access origin="http://meusite.com.br"

Onde estaria o erro? Qual seria a diferença entre testar uma aplicação com o phonegap serve e pelo apk gerado pelo build phonegap?

Obrigado!!

Comment: `android.permission.INTERNET` ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387007/phonegap-build-permissions-in-android

Comment: Minhas permissões estão assim:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: O Cordova/PhoneGap por padrão vem com um "bloqueio" ao acesso de Internet pelo aplicativo. Mas na sua própria documentação, possui um guia muito bem explicado, aonde ensina a tirar esse bloqueio, para que seja possível acessar a Web pelo app. Segue o Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#supported-cordova-platforms

Answer (score 3):

Bom, depois de muito tentar, descobri onde estava o problema:

Na nova versão do Phonegap, ele cria no config.xml as seguintes linhas:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://www.diskebeba.com.br/aplicativo" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" /> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Eu apaguei TODAS e substitui apenas por:

access origin="*" launch-external="yes"

Apenas lembrando que foi testado apenas no Android.

Agradeço as respostas e/ou comentários e espero que isto ajude de alguma forma.